# How to extract words pairs from nested lists

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column that contains a list of sentences (a nested list)

**Aim**

Some of the sentences contain words from one reference list I have, and some from a second list, and some from both. I would like to extract all words from the two lists of words in each sentence and join them if they are both present from each sentence.

**Example**

```
ReportText1<-list(c("4 oesophagus biopsies.","Three EMRs seen"))
ReportText2<-list("stomach EMRx1")
ReportText3<-list("stomach biopsy seen pinned on cork","three biopsies")
ReportText<-c(ReportText1, ReportText2,ReportText3)

ReportID         Report_Text
1                [1] 4 oesophagus biopsies.
                 [2] Three EMRs seen
2                [1] stomach EMRx1
3                [1] stomach biopsy seen pinned on cork
                 [2] three biopsies
```

**Desired output**

```
ReportID         Report_Text                             Output
1                [1] 4 oesophagus biopsies.              oesophagus:biopsies,EMR:
                 [2] Three EMRs seen                     
2                [1] stomach EMRx1                       stomach:EMR
3                [1] stomach biopsy seen pinned on cork  stomach:biopsy,biopsies:
                 [2] three biopsies
```

Lists I am using:

To get the type of specimen (ie biopsy or EMR etc).

```
HistolType <- function() {
  
  #First standardise the terms
  
    tofind <-
      paste(
        c(
          "Resection","Biopsy","EMR","ESD","bx","biopsy","biopsies"),
        collapse = "|"
      )
    return(tofind)
  }
```

To get the location of the specimen

```
LocationList<-function(){
  
  tofind <-
    paste(
      c(
        
        "Stomach","Antrum","Duodenum","Oesophagus","GOJ"
      ),
      collapse = "|"
    )
  
  return(tofind)
  
}
```

**Attempt**

I am assuming that the the approach should be to use a nested `lapply` but I don't seem to be able to be able to apply the extraction within a nested `lapply`. The inner `lapply` doesn't seem to iterate through each sentence separately and concatenate per sentence, it only concatenates at the end

```
lapply(SelfOGD_Dunn2$Macroscopy, function (x) 
        lapply(x, function(y) paste(
             str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(LocationList())),":",
             str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(HistolType())))))
```

**Actual output**

```
ReportID         Report_Text                             Output
1                [1] 4 oesophagus biopsies.              "c(\"oesophagus\" : c(\"EMR\", \"bx\")"
                 [2] Three EMRs seen                     
2                [1] stomach EMRx1                       stomach : EMR
3                [1] stomach biopsy seen pinned on cork  "c(\"stomach\" : c(\"biopsy\", \"biopsies\")"
                 [2] three biopsies
```

I guess an alternative is to extract each list separately along with the index of the sentence that the word was found at and then merge according to index? If anyone knows how to do this as an alternative I'd love to know.

Comment: Can you share `dput` of your dataframe ?

Comment: @RonakShah I'm finding it difficult to add a nested list to a dataframe so I have placed the creation of the list on here.

Comment: Try `lapply(SelfOGD_Dunn2$Macroscopy, function (x) lapply(x, function(y) Map(paste, str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(LocationList())), str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(HistolType())), MoreArgs = list(sep=":"))))`  Not tested though

Comment: Great thanks @akrun.  Please post as an answer.  An you explain the use of map? Why doesn't the inner lapply work without this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are `paste`ed from corresponding `list` elements (`str_extract_all` returns a `list` output), we can use `Map`

```
lapply(SelfOGD_Dunn2$Macroscopy, function (x)
   lapply(x, function(y) 
     Map(paste, str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(LocationList())), 
                str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(HistolType())),
          MoreArgs = list(sep=":"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a nested `lapply` you need to `collapse` the output of a list items from the inner list:

```
lapply(ReportText, function (x) 
               paste( lapply(x, function(y) 
                                 paste(
                                      str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(LocationList()), simplify = T),":",
                                      str_extract_all(tolower(y),tolower(HistolType()), simplify = T))
                                      ), 
                                      collapse = ","
                    )

      )

#[[1]]
#[1] "oesophagus : biopsies, : emr"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "stomach : emr"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "stomach : biopsy"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] " : biopsies"
```